# how to get specific doc within 5 seconds?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have encountered the following issue: When I enter the full name of a company to search for it and set the timeout to 5 seconds, the search results cannot be found. However, if I increase the timeout to 30 seconds, the search results can be found and the company is ranked first with a score of 84.97272. The score for the company ranked second is only 25.934332. I would like to know if there is any way to retrieve the search results within 5 seconds. The query statement is shown below:

```
{
    "from":0, "size":120,
    "timeout": "5s",
     "query": {
         "function_score": {
             "query": {
                 "bool": {
                     "should": [{
                             "match": {
                                 "name": {"query":"{{query_name}}", "minimum_should_match":"4<85%"}
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "match": {
                                 "shortName": {
                                     "query": "{{query_name}}",
                                     "boost": 2.9
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "term": {
                                 "name.keyword": {
                                     "value": "{{query_name}}",
                                     "boost": 2.0
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "match_phrase": {
                                 "name": "{{query_name}}"
                             }
                         }                         
                     ],
                     "minimum_should_match": 1
                 }
             },
             "functions": [{
                     "field_value_factor": {
                         "field": "weight",
                         "missing": 0
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "field_value_factor": {
                         "field": "viewCount",
                         "modifier": "ln1p",
                         "missing": 0
                     },
                     "weight":2
                 }
             ],
             "score_mode": "sum",
             "boost_mode": "sum"
         }
     }     
 }
```

Comment: hey @zhuguowei, did you try any of the suggested ideas? were useful?

Comment: No, but it was back to normal later. I'm not sure if ES did some merging work.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to return 120 results (seems a good use case for pagination, given your function score query), it'll certainly help reducing the response size